# What is the meaning of the term "linear"

Tags: linear-algebra

$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+...+a_nx_n=$ is called a linear equation because it represents the equation of a line in an n dimensional space. So "linear" comes from the word "line".Basically there should not be any higher power of x failing which the graph of the function will not be a straight line.

simillarly

$a(x)y+b(x)y'+c(x)y"+d(x)y'''+...+q(x)=0$ is also called linear differential equation because all the derivatives have power equal to 1 which is similar to the above definition of a linear equation.

A function f is called linear if:
$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
and
$f(cx)=cf(x)$. Here c is a constant.
In this definition of linearity of function "$f$" what does the word linear means? How does it relate to a straight line?

Finally what does the term linear means in case of linear vector spaces? Where is the reference to a straight line?

So, whether linear is just a word used in different contexts? Does it have different meaning in different situation? Or linearity refers to some relation to a straight line? At Least please explain how the linearity of function f and linear vector space relate to the equation of a line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concept of Linearity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331460/concept-of-linearity). Further reading: [What does 'linear' mean in Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62789/what-does-linear-mean-in-linear-algebra) and [What is linearity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929576/what-is-linearity?noredirect=1&lq=1), [What is linearity numerically and geometrically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794582/what-is-linear-numerically-and-geometrically-speaking?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Ultimately, I think it all comes down to straight lines in one way or another.

Comment: may be related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Answer (score 1):

Linear functions are of the form

$$f(x) = ax$$

where solely the linear term is nonzero. The relation with straight lines is that if you see $x$ as a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $x$, $f(x)$ and $0$ lie on a single line.

A function of that form will automatically satisfy

$$ f(x + y) = a(x + y) = ax + ay = f(x) + f(y)$$

and

$$ f(cx) = acx = cax = c f(x).$$

If, in a linear vector space, you draw a line between elements $A$ and $B$, then all points on that line, i.e. points of the form

$$ (1 - t) A + (t)B$$

will belong to the linear vector space. A consequence is that in a linear vector space, 
 you can take $\textit{linear combinations}$ of elements, without leaving the space, i.e.

$$ A, B \in V \rightarrow c_1 A + c_2 B \in V \qquad \forall c_1, c_2 \in F$$

where $F$ is the field you used in defining the vector space.